# Mercurial - how to enable/create visual graph

Tags: mercurial, graph

At our company we can access the remote repository web interface which has a 'graph' view where you can see an HTML page with a colored graph of the changeset structure/history.  How can you enable this on your local clone?

We do use the [Graph Log](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/GraphlogExtension) extension which is nice, but I prefer the HTML version with colors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a fast check you can use `hg serve` command, that will deploy the **mercurial built-in web server**  which includes a **graph view** of the repository it's useful and you can fine tune it with the `.hgrc` file, but for a **permanent** setup I will recommend to use a **dedicated** web server and a **Mercurial CGI Server**

More info on the **hg wiki** [hg serve page](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/hgserve) and [Mercurial CGI Server page](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CGIinstall)